# PHP Push elements into array

Tags: php

Hello Friends My Code is as Follow:
Here I am iterating over for loop

```
foreach($row_result as $results)
{
  $f = fopen("jigsaw.csv", "a+");
  $new_array = array();
  $content = $results->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('seo-company'))->geTtext();
  $test = array();
  if($i==1)
  {
    $Orgnisation_name = $content;
    $concate = array_push($test,$Orgnisation_name);
    echo "\n";
  }  
  if($i==2)
  {
    echo $Website = $content;
    echo "\n";
  }  
  if($i==3)
  {
    echo $HeadQuarters = $content;
    echo "\n";
  }  
  if($i==4)
  {
    echo $Phone = $content;
    echo "\n";
  }  
  if($i==5)
  {
    echo $Industries = $content;
    echo "\n";
  }  
  if($i==6)
  {
    echo $Employees = $content;
    echo "\n";
  }  
  if($i==7)
  {
    echo $Revenue = $content;
    echo "\n";
  }  
  if($i==8)
  {
    echo $Ownership = $content;
    echo "\n";
  }  
  $i++;
}
```

- Here I want to push one by one element into concate array and finally
  save it into mysql php database.
  When I try to push it into concate array its printing me 1 which is wrong 
  What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) return value is:

> Returns the new number of elements in the array.

So 1 is the number of elements in array.

Seems that you will always have 1, because you call `$i++` and according to your code, block with `array_push` will be executed once.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use array_push? `$concate = array_push($test,$Orgnisation_name);` $test is blank at this point. If you just want to add an item to the $concate array, `$concate[] = $Orgnisation_name;` is enough.